# Копирование разных файлов в одну папку

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Здравствуйте!

Как написать программу, которая копирует с разных мест (пути к файлам прописаны в текстовом файле degh.txt) в одну папку (папку куда копировать нужно указывать самому). Программа необходима для облегчения работы дежурному в сборе рисунков. В сети нашел только копирование папки в папку.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать WinAPI
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363852(VS.85).aspx

Comment: интересно, что заставляет людей использовать все эти древности типа Delphi 7? Хорошо хоть не перфокарты

Comment: спасибо всем за помощь, вопрос решен

Comment: @DreamChild, интересно - отвечаю. Для таких задач, как эта, Delphi 7 подходит идеально.
Например, у "клиентов" никогда не появится ошибка типа "msvc###.dll не найден"

Comment: @Katilina знаете, обычно стоит немного попользоваться нормальной современной IDE с нормальным современным ЯП, после чего на подобный хлам уже не тянет - за минувшие 11 (или сколько там) лет инструменты разработки шагнули далеко вперед в плане удобства, скорости разработки, отладки, рефакторинга (список можно продолжить), поэтому до сих пор использовать этот замечательный когда-то инструмент - это все равно, что ходить пешком из Москвы во Владивосток, имея возможность купить билет на самолет

Comment: в данном случае делфи 7 может быть вполне нормальным решением. Максимум я бы перешел на 2007.

А то летать с Бирюлево в Кремль на Боинге, имя возможность проехать на вертолете как то не по феншую:)

Comment: Ох не знаю-не знаю. Особенно учитывая, что разработчики Delphi только к 2008 году задумались о существовании Юникода (также же можно вспомнить кучу других передовых достижений инженерной мысли конца каменного века, о которых команда Delphi предпочитала ничего не знать вплоть до нынешних времен)

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так:

```
var
  FilesList: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
  sNew: string;
begin
  sNew := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter('путь к папке в которую копируем');
  FilesList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    FilesList.LoadFromFile('имя файла со списком.txt'); //Загружаем список файлов.
    for i := 0 to FilesList.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if not FileExists(FilesList[i]) then 
        Continue; //Минуем не существующие файлы
      if not CopyFile(PChar(FilesList[i]), PChar(sNew + ExtractFileName(FilesList[i])), False) then //Путь назначения + старое имя
        ShowMessage('Ошибка при копировании файла: ' + FilesList[i]);
    end;
  finally
    FilesList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: >Преподаватели ВУЗов СУЗов и т.д. а ещё Delphi 7 самыйпопулярный ответ на запрос "скачать delphi" в гугле.

Про ВУЗы-СУЗы я в курсе, сам когда-то учился в таком институте. Речь о том, что есть уйма программистов (не студентов и не преподавателей), которые по-прежнему используют этот самый Delphi 7. А что касается самого популярного запроса..хм..уж не знаю, но мне почему-то всегода казалось, что выбирать инструменты разработки нужно не по популярности запросов в гугле, а по иным, боле объективным критериям

Comment: Версия делфи означает лишь расширение компилятора и самого языка, +/- какие-то оптимизации. То что delphi старо, совсем не значит что оно менее эффективно чем xe5. Зачем качать IDE в 5 гб, если не будешь пользоваться теми же дженериками и класс-хелперами, инлаинами, классовыми методами в структурах? Я ими пользуюсь т.к. они очень удобны и сильно упрощают жизнь, другое дело студент или новый разработчик. Которым параллельны новинки, одному решить задачу, другому чтобы было легче учится по книге. А профи уже подбирает IDE под требования.

Comment: Не помню книг в которых все с 0 описывается хотя бы в Delphi 2010. Тот же запрос "литература про delphi", выдает ссылки на динозавров.

Comment: Разработка delphi идет вперед очень быстрыми темпами, за последние 3 года было сделано: x64 битный компилятор, MacOS, iOS, Android, единая база кода и огромный набор компонент для разработки кросс-платформенных приложений, базы данных, live-bindings. Начинаешь писать книгу, как тут же рождается ещё одна версия delphi удивляя чем-то новым. Сколько языков и IDE развивается с такой же скоростью и имеет такие возможности?
Вот по этому не так много написано книг, на русском по крайней мере. На английском литература есть).

Comment: Используют старые delphi, т.к. они просты, удобны, переносимы. Самой большой проблемы из-за которой я перешел на Delphi XE, с 7й - было наличие Unicode. Только потом уже научился новым фокусам.

Comment: >Сколько языков и IDE развивается с такой же скоростью и имеет такие возможности?

а уж это, извините, вообще анекдот. Да практически любой язык развивается быстрее, чем Delphi, где котором всего несколько лет назад появились дженерики и Юникод, которые в других языках есть с незапамятных времен. А уж про IDE говорить даже не приходится - взгляните на Visual Studio или Intellij Idea - они настолько удобны и современны, что Rad Studio по сравнению с ними - детская игрушка